Funds sent to wrong chain
I was supposed to send these funds in a Safe contract on Base Chain but I ended up not realizing that it was with Blast's rpc and I sent it to the address on the Blast network.
As it is a new network, I have not seen it reported, I would like to know if there is a way to recover the funds?
Address:
0xB8568F224fF87A256E9B5dA8Ef31333A98190a91
Thx

To begin with, don't do anything.
There is a chance that you can deploy a safe contract with the same address in the other chain, and that way claim the assets. But if you try that and fail, the success probability goes down, fast.
What I recommend is forking the chain where the assets are (and where you don't have a safe). Then play around with safe deployment in the forked chain until you are certain you can reproduce the steps in the real blockchain.
Remember, you only have one chance to get this right in the real blockchain.
Also, it may not be possible to get the same address. You should probably check Safe documentation to see what the options are.

I understand this must be a stressful situation, fortunately you should be able to recover your funds. Since both Blast and Base are EVM-based, and both have proxy factories deployed at the same address, you will be able to deploy a Safe on Blast with the address of your Safe on Base, and hence recover your funds.
Can you please read this guide and watch this video? I can only advise you to follow every step carefully.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
